# remove array object by its index

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to remove an array object from an array. First, I loop to the array of objects and if that array match to the given filter, then remove that object. Below is what I've tried but unfortunately not working, any help, ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations please?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var n_array = [{ 'name' : 'jason', 'age' : '24'},{ 'name' : 'jason2', 'age' : '20'}];

  console.log(n_array);
  
  for(var i = 0; i < n_array.length; i++){
   if(n_array[i].name==='jason'){
     n_array.splice(i,0);
   }
  }
  console.log(n_array);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `delete`.

**[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)** is the reference to it, this is exactly what you looking for.

```
if (n_array[i].name === 'jason') {
    delete n_array[i].name;
}
```

> The delete operator removes a property from an object.

Comment: wow, it works, can you explain me a little bit about that 'delete' thing?

Comment: You can read the linked reference description. It's too long to tell you here, because of character limitation.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and not [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to remove element from array.

   ```
   n_array.splice(i, 1);
   ```

```js
var n_array = [{
    'name': 'jason',
    'age': '24'
}, {
    'name': 'jason2',
    'age': '20'
}];

for (var i = 0; i < n_array.length; i++) {
    if (n_array[i].name === 'jason') {
        n_array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
console.log(n_array);
```

2. You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove an element from array.

   ```
   var n_array = [{
       'name': 'jason',
       'age': '24'
   }, {
       'name': 'jason2',
       'age': '20'
   }];

   n_array = n_array.filter(function(obj) {
       return obj.name !== 'jason';
   });
   console.log(n_array);
   ```

```js
var n_array = [{
    'name': 'jason',
    'age': '24'
}, {
    'name': 'jason2',
    'age': '20'
}];

n_array = n_array.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.name !== 'jason';
});
console.log(n_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you
n_array.slice(i); replace this with n_array.splice(i, 1);

slice() method is used to select the elements from array

Answer (score 0):

Problem with yours code is splice syntax

splice syntax is:
array.splice(index,howmany element going to delete,value_item1,.....,value_itemX);

In urs code you are using `n_array.splice(i,0)`;  so you are giving 0 element to delete.

Make it Like

```
var n_array = [{ 'name' : 'jason', 'age' : '24'},{ 'name' : 'jason2', 'age' : '20'}];

  console.log(n_array);

  for(var i = 0; i < n_array.length; i++){
   if(n_array[i].name==='jason2'){
     n_array.splice(i,1);
   }
  }
  console.log(n_array);
```

Hope it will help